# Leaky Stack Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a LeakyStack where the stack size is 5 and the capacity is 10. Following should be the end result -

[image]

Some notes are :

If at a point, the stack (i.e. the inner array of the stack) is as follows:   [4, 1, 3, 2, 5, None, None, None, None, None], where “4” is the bottom of the stack and “5” is the top of the stack, and a new number “8” is pushed in the stack, the stack should be as follows:  [None, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8, None, None, None, None, None].  This means “4” is ignored (leaked).

If at a point the stack is as follows: [2, 3, None, None, None, None, None, 8, 9, 1], where “8” is the bottom of the stack and “3” is the top of the stack, and a new number “5” is pushed in the stack, the stack will become: [2, 3, 5, None, None, None, None, None, 9, 1]. This means “8” is ignored (leaked).

Other special situations should be considered such as performing a pop operation when the stack is empty.

This is my code. Right now I need to fix something at the `__init__` and at the end I think.

```
class Full(Exception):
pass

class Empty(Exception):
pass

class MyLeakyStack:

def __init__(self, maxlen, capacity, len):
    # note: this function is partially completed
    self.data = []
    self._maxlen = maxlen
    self._capacity = capacity  # size of the circular array
    self._storage = [None] * capacity  # initialise storage room, this is treated as a circular array

def __len__(self):
    return self.len

def push(self,x):
    if self.len == maxsize:
        del self.data[0]
        self.data.append(x)
    else:
        self.data.append(x)
        self.len += 1

def pop(self):
    self.len = -1
    self.data.pop()

def is_empty(selfs):
   return len(self.data)==0

def __str__(self):
    return ' '.join(str(self.data[i]) for i in range(len(self.data)))

if __name__ == '__main__':

 S = MyLeakyStack(5, 10)   # stack size should be 5 and the capacity of the array should be 10

 for i in range(12):
    try:
        S.push(i)
        print("after push "+str(i), S._storage)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

 for i in range(6):
    try:
        a=S.pop()
        print("after pop "+str(a), S._storage)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, S._storage)

 for i in range(5):
    try:
        S.push(i+100)
        print("after push " + str(i+100), S._storage)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, S._storage)


a = MyLeakyStack()
a.push(1)
a.push(2)
a.push(3)
a.push(4)
a.push(5)
a.push(6)
a.push(8)
a.push(0)
a.pop(1)
print(len(a))
```

Comment: You can correct the indentation in your code by selecting all of the code and pressing `CTRL` + `K`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't understand why are you passing "*len*" to the *__init__* function, Since you are not using that parameter.

Secondly, even if you were doing something with it (i can see you are calling *self.len* in the other object functions), you can't use the word "len" to name a variable, because its reserved for the *len()* function.

So, I would say you don't need that when you initialise your object, because as soon as it is created it's length is always going to be 0.

I changed a your code to match the required output.

```
class Full(Exception):
    pass

class Empty(Exception):
    pass

class MyLeakyStack:

    def __init__(self, maxlen, capacity):
        # note: this function is partially completed
        self._maxlen = maxlen
        self._capacity = capacity  # size of the circular array
        self._storage = [None] * capacity  # initialise storage room, this is treated as a circular array
        self.f = 0
        self.r = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return (self._capacity - self.r + self.f) % self._capacity

    def push(self,x):
        self._storage[self.f] = x
        self.f = (self.f + 1) % self._capacity
        if len(self) > self._maxlen:
            l = self._storage[self.r]
            self._storage[self.r] = None
            self.r = (self.r + 1) % self._capacity
            raise Full("Reach stack limit, forget element " + str(l))

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty("Stack is empty")

        pop = self._storage[self.f - 1]
        self._storage[self.f - 1] = None
        self.f = (self.f - 1) % self._capacity
        return pop

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.f == self.r

    def __str__(self):
        return " " + str(self._storage)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    S = MyLeakyStack(5, 10)   # stack size should be 5 and the capacity of the array should be 10

    for i in range(12):
        try:
            S.push(i)
            print("after push "+str(i), S._storage)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("after push "+str(i), S._storage)

    for i in range(6):
        try:
            a=S.pop()
            print("after pop "+str(a), S._storage)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, S._storage)

    for i in range(5):
        try:
            S.push(i+100)
            print("after push " + str(i+100), S._storage)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, S._storage)


a = MyLeakyStack(5, 10)
a.push(1)
a.push(2)
a.push(3)
a.push(4)
a.push(5)
a.push(6)
a.push(8)
a.push(0)
a.pop()
print(str(len(a)))
```

Here's the output I get, that is kind of the same of what you're asked to have.

```
after push 0 [0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
after push 1 [0, 1, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
after push 2 [0, 1, 2, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
after push 3 [0, 1, 2, 3, None, None, None, None, None, None]
after push 4 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None]
Reach stack limit, forget element 0
after push 5 [None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None, None, None, None]
Reach stack limit, forget element 1
after push 6 [None, None, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, None, None, None]
Reach stack limit, forget element 2
after push 7 [None, None, None, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, None, None]
Reach stack limit, forget element 3
after push 8 [None, None, None, None, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, None]
Reach stack limit, forget element 4
after push 9 [None, None, None, None, None, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Reach stack limit, forget element 5
after push 10 [10, None, None, None, None, None, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Reach stack limit, forget element 6
after push 11 [10, 11, None, None, None, None, None, 7, 8, 9]
after pop 11 [10, None, None, None, None, None, None, 7, 8, 9]
after pop 10 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 7, 8, 9]
after pop 9 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 7, 8, None]
after pop 8 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 7, None, None]
after pop 7 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
Stack is empty [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
after push 100 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 100, None, None]
after push 101 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 100, 101, None]
after push 102 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 100, 101, 102]
after push 103 [103, None, None, None, None, None, None, 100, 101, 102]
after push 104 [103, 104, None, None, None, None, None, 100, 101, 102]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 77, in <module>
    a.push(6)
  File "so.py", line 27, in push
    raise Full("Reach stack limit, forget element " + str(l))
__main__.Full: Reach stack limit, forget element 1
```

Consider that it ends with an error because that's an Exception you raised. If you want the script not to stop, you need to use a try-except block.